# Error using apache -common-validator --java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule

Tags: java, apache, google-app-engine

I am using following jars-
commons-validator-1.4.0 ; commons.logging-1.2 ; commons.digester-1.8 ;commons.beanutils-1.8.3
commons.collections-3.2.1

but keeps on getting same error at line -

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Rule
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
              com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
```

This is the code i am writing -

```
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("validator-name-required.xml");
// Create an instance of ValidatorResources to initialize from an xml file.
  ValidatorResources resources = new ValidatorResources(in);
```

Please help its been a day i am stuck into this error !! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Finally i am able to do this. I have used the following jars -

commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-validator-1.4.0.jar

and this works :)

Answer (score 0):

Its look like that "org.apache.commons.digester.Rule" class was not found, Version 2.1 of digester have Rule.class, download this version and try.

Comment: I checked commons.digester-1.8 , it also have a rule class, then check your project build path and try to find "org.apache.commons.digester.Rule" class.

Comment: Thanks @killer,but i have already tried with both these jars. Can  you please try creating some dummy project and try it .I have mentioned the jars i am using in the main thread ..

Comment: don't try both jar, use only one jar with one version only, don't mix up same jar with different versions.

Comment: i am not using both jars simultaneously , i have tried using each of them separately...

Comment: have you find the "org.apache.commons.digester.Rule" class in your buildpath?

Comment: how can i find this class in the build path ? i am watching the jar name in BuildPath->Libraries in eclipse. Collapsing the jar says - Javadoc loc(None), Source Attchament(none) etc

Comment: Go to your project explorer in eclipse, and then click in the "Referenced Libraries" of your project, there you get all the jar and the classes, then try to browse and find your desired class file.

Comment: Yes it shows this class..but still giving the error

Comment: what are the other jars, instead of commons-validator-1.4.0 ; commons.logging-1.2 ; commons.digester-1.8 ;commons.beanutils-1.8.3 commons.collections-3.2.1 you use in your project..